# Integrated Authentication Error with connection to SQL server from Pyspark

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I am preforming below steps to connect to SQL server 2016 with integratedSecurity option "true" from Pyspark script on Linux machine. I've downloaded SQL JDBC driver from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and using the jar file for java version 8 and dll file from /auth/x64 folder under download as environment has java version "1.8.0_291" with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Script-

```
$ cat ReadData.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Connection-Test').config('spark.driver.extraClassPath','/home/user1/mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:/home/user1/mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll').getOrCreate()
spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://prodsqlserver.domainName.com:3341;databaseName=PHOENIX_DW;integratedSecurity=true").option("dbtable","DWH.AGENT").option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").load().show()
```

Command Executed-

```
$ spark2-submit --driver-class-path mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar --jars mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar ReadData.py
```

Error-

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o79.load.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3206)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:72)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4015)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:85)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4004)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3272)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2768)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:51)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4014)
        ... 28 more
```

I've been trying to connect this for hours now, but each time I end up with same error. How do I get this fixed?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64` suggests that you need to add another jar

Comment: Hi Werner, my understanding is that mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll is required here as we are connecting to SQL server using Active Directory (not user/password combo). is there another jar file needed? I have tried mentioning mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64.dll with spark-submit command in --jars option along with jre8.jar, it results in the same error.

Comment: Yes, that was the file that I meant. I should have written `dll`... Not sure how to provide a dll to pyspark, as I am not too familiar with Spark on Windows.

Comment: I further looked at it, looks like .dll file only works with windows. For Linux there are different options

Comment: _Integrated Auth_ means that the **current** logged user tries to connect to SQL Server as *Windows user* **WITHOUT** specify the password.